# How can I ask this question, about helping a friend who is in the same course as me, in a way which fits the site?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am active on other SE sites but not here, thus I am unfamiliar with the local norms & scope. There is a question which I would like to ask but I am not sure how to phrase it so it will work here. Here is my current draft:

> Title: How can I help/tutor a friend who is taking the same course as me?
>
> I am a STEM major and have a good friend who is a non-STEM major. We are both taking a CS minor, me because it is relevant to my field of study and he because he wants a backup plan in case his preferred career path doesn't work out. Thus, while I am a much stronger math student than he, we end up taking the same courses where the CS minor is concerned.
>
> Part of the CS minor's requirements are a series of math courses. We took the penultimate one last year, together, and I struggled with helping him through it. These are not math classes or concepts which either of us have been formally exposed to before. However, I have self-studied some things, and am better at grasping the concepts the first time around (during the lecture), while he needs more reinforcement and multiple explanations for more complicated ideas.
>
> Because we are friends we naturally did the homework together (doing homework in groups is encouraged by the professors in this series of classes). I felt awkward sometimes, as I had two goals the whole time: do the homework as quickly as I could do it well, and teach him the concepts. Our working relationship was not quite that of tutor and student, which I have more experience with - I tutored calculus on the side - but it was also not that of two equal friends struggling through the homework together. Besides homework, we also prepared for tests together, and I shared my notes with him.
>
> With the coming of fall classes, I have been thinking about how I could improve the next time our classes overlap, which will be in the winter term. **How could I better approach helping/tutoring a friend in the same course as me?**

My goal in asking this question would be to find ways to adjust my mindset and/or tutoring style with him so that we could both succeed in the math courses together. Is there anything wrong with the current formulation of the question? Should I adjust the wording or scope of the question? I am aware it is somewhat opinion-based and broad; is it too much so? Is there any information I left out which would be helpful to answerers? Should I mention how I approached this the last time, and if so, where?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. Others may disagree.

Comment: Just for information: this question has been posted on the main site as '[How can I help/tutor a friend who is taking the same course as me?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/25541)' on 2022-08-23.